# Remove objects in environment with for loop

Tags: r, loops, object, for-loop

Brand new to loops here and can't seem to find an answer.  I'm trying to remove consecutively named, character objects with a for loop.  What am I doing wrong?

```
query1 <- c("x")
query2 <- c("x")
query3 <- c("x")
query4 <- c("x")
query5 <- c("x")

for (i in 1:5) {
  rm(list(paste(query),i))
}
```

Comment: I think that you want `rm(list(paste(query,I, sep="")))`

Comment: Or `rm(list=ls(pattern="query\\d+"))` or to be exact `rm(list=ls(pattern="query[12345]"))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a small modification

```
for (i in 1:5) {
    rm(list = paste("query",i,sep  = ""))
}
```